# How to Add "itemReviewed" in PHP?

Tags: schema

I added schema but the itemviewed field is missing, what should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igMFj.png)

I tried to add the itemviewed field but google still gives me an error

```
<div class="VotesCn">
<div class="Prct">
                        <div id="TPVotes" data-percent="{{$currentMovie->getRatingStar() * 10}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-ratings" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                        <input id="hint_current" type="hidden" value="">
                        <input id="score_current" type="hidden"
                            value="{{$currentMovie->getRatingStar()}}">
                        <div id="star" data-score="{{$currentMovie->getRatingStar()}}"
                            style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
                        <br />
                        (<strong class="num-rating">{{$currentMovie->getRatingCount()}}</strong> lượt, đánh giá: <strong
                            id="average_score">{{$currentMovie->getRatingStar()}}</strong>
                        trên 10)<br />
                        <span class="post-ratings-text" id="hint"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope
                        itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                        
                        <span itemprop="ratingValue">{{$currentMovie->getRatingStar()}}</span>
                        <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="{{$currentMovie->getRatingCount()}}">
                        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="10" />
                        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1" />
                    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me check if this code is correct?